# LINQ Statement Optimization - Seeking advice for better design

Tags: c#, linq, wcf-data-services, odata

I am seeking advice on how to better design the following LINQ query (using WCF Data Services).  The requirement is to display a list of Employees via a ComboBox.

The DB table structure is as follows:

An Employee could be assigned to many Projects and a Project could have many Employees.  This relationship is designed via 3 tables: `[Employees] 1--* [EmployeeProjects] *--1 [Projects]`. In dot nation, it would something like if I was traversing the object tree: `Employee.EmployeeProjects.Project`.

The following LINQ statement return a list of `EmployeeProjects`, but what I am after is a list of Employee that are part of those certain Projects.  Ideally, it makes sense to execute an `IQueryable<Employee>`, but I don't know how to structure my LINQ statement because of the `EmployeeProjects` link (many).  Do you see my dilemma?

I perform an `IQueryable<EmployeeProject>` because, as you can see from my LINQ statement below, I never have to deal with the "Many" aspect since the Employee and Project sides are both 1 relationships.  After I get the list of `EmployeeProjects`, I perform another `.Select()` statement on it to return what I'm ultimately after, i.e. a list of unique Employee's Names, e.g. `.Select(results => results.Employee.Name).Distinct()`.

```
private IQueryable<EmployeeProject> GetEmployeeProjects()
{
    var employeeProjects =  service
        .CustomQuery<EmployeeProject>()
        .Where(et => ep.Project.Name == "TrackerX 43" ||
                     ep.Project.Name == "AccountingX 11" ||
                     ep.Project.Name == "TopX 2" ||
                     ep.Project.Name == "SiteX 32" ||
                     ep.Project.Name == "BuildingX 3" ||
                     ep.Project.Name == "ReportX 321" ||
                     ep.Project.Name == "PrototypeX 78" ||
                     ep.Project.Name == ... more ...)
        .OrderBy(ep => ep.Employee.Name)
        .Select(ep => new EmployeeProject
        {
            Id = ep.Id
            Project = new Project
            {
                Name = ep.Project.Name
            },
            Employee = new Employee
            {
                Id = ep.Employee.Id,
                Name = ep.Employeet.Name
            }
        });

    return employeeProjects;
}
```

Any advice on designing this better would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to create a new `EmployeeProject` or can you simple return the existing one?

One thing you could do is combine the strings into an array and compare them like this:

```
//Move inside the method call if you need it to be dynamic.
private readonly string[] compareProjectNames = new[]
{ 
   "AccountingX 11", "TopX 2", "SiteX 32", 
   "BuildingX 3", "ReportX 321", "PrototypeX 78"
};
private IQueryable<EmployeeProject> GetEmployeeProjects()
{
    var employeeProjects =  service.CustomQuery<EmployeeProject>()
        .Where(et => compareProjectNames.Contains(ep.Project.Name))
        .OrderBy(ep => ep.Employee.Name)
        .Select(ep => new EmployeeProject
        {
            Id = ep.Id,
            Project = new Project
            {
                Name = ep.Project.Name
            },
            Employee = new Employee
            {
                Id = ep.Employee.Id,
                Name = ep.Employee.Name
            }
        });
    return employeeProjects;
}
```

**EDIT:**

After reading your post a little more carefully, you might also be looking for something like this to find distinct project names

```
List<EmployeeProject> employeeProjects = new List<EmployeeProject>();
employeeProjects
   .GroupBy(et => et.Project.Name)
   .Select(grp => grp.First());
```

Alternatively, in 1 statement

```
List<EmployeeProject> employeeProjects = new List<EmployeeProject>();
employeeProjects
        .Where(et => compareProjectNames.Contains(et.Project.Name))
        .GroupBy(cust => cust.Project.Name) //groups them by name, so no need to order
        .Select(grp => grp.First()) //selects the first distinct name per group
        .Select(ep => new EmployeeProject
        {
            Id = ep.Id,
            Project = new Project
            {
                Name = ep.Project.Name
            },
            Employee = new Employee
            {
                Id = ep.Employee.Id,
                Name = ep.Employee.Name
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think you should emphasize that the logic is intentionally backwards, so that you use the list of constraints and .Compares (or .Contains) the field.  Though you can do it the normal way (field.Contains(constraint_array)), the backwards way produces a more succinct SQL query.

Comment: I fixed the Compares -> Contains thing because that was a typo. But I'm not sure what you mean as far as the other way. `str.Contains(arrayOfStr)` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  That's what I get for just checking something rather than trying it myself.  I mis-read something and though it would allow the other way (what I really read was calling one LINQ to SQL query within another) Everything else I said still stands.

Comment: Thank you @Corylulu for your solution.  I've updated my question/problem since I didn't really explain what I'm looking for.  I don't need to create any new records or actually after EmployeeProjects.  I am looking for a distinct list of Employees that are assigned to a specific list of Projects.  Hope this helps, and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you use EF on the server side, you should be able to completely hide the EmployeeProject table from the clients. EF should be able to turn your DB structure into two entity sets (Employees and Projects) with a Many-Many relationship between them (in detail it would create two 1-Many one-direction relationships).

So from the client it would look like an Employees entity set where each instance has a property Projects, which is the list of projects the employee participates in. And similarly an entity set Projects where each instance has a property Employees which is a list of employees assigned to that project.

Then the above query could be much simpler (using the URL notation for shortness, the LINQ version is sort of obvious, also simplified the list of project names):

~/Projects?$filter=(Name eq 'TopX 2') or (Name eq 'SiteX 32')&$expand=Employess

This would get you all the projects with the specified names, and for each project all its assigned employees.

This assumes that the middle table is purely there for joining the other two tables, if you also store some additional information about the connection in it, then this would not work.

Comment: Hello Vitek, thanks for your response, but the EmployeeProject class/table is needed since it has additional properties that need to be included and offer other details.  Does this help?  Thanks...

Comment: Then as noted in my answer, that approach can't be used. What you have looks like the only viable approach already.

Comment: Thanks Vitek for the response.  Just to confirm, though I would like to return a collection of Employees, there is no way and thus must first return a collection of EmployeeProjects?  It just doesn't seem right, that is all.  I tried seeking alternatives, like using .SelectMany(), but wasn't sure how to massage it into my statement.

Comment: There might be a way using Any/All and SelectMany (turn the query around basically), but I'm not sure if it would help you that much. If all you need is the employee information, then in the last Select only ask for properties of the employee. You can also append .AsEnumerable() and then any more detailed projection. Anything after the AsEnumerable will be processed on the client only (so you won't run into limitations of the OData query language).